# Unexpected delays in jquery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have a list-element that is initially set to `max-height: 200px; overflow-y:hidden;`. Beneath that element there is a `h3`-element you can click to show the entire list. For that purpose, I animated the `maxHeight`-property of the element with the jQuery animate() method. The animation should last 1.2 seconds. After that, the text below the list changes from "show more" to "show less". When you click on it, this animation is reversed, again with a duration of 1.2 seconds, after which the text changes back to "show more".
Everything works fine, except for some unexpected delays: After the first animation which raises the `maxHeight`-property of the list, it takes another second or so for the text to change as well. Then, if you click the "show less" text, nothing happens for about a seconds before the animation starts. 
What is causing these unexpected delays?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GinSan/z83cpbvj/)

**Edit:** As Wa Kei explained, this delay is caused by the "excess" height, since the element is actually less than 1200px high. So how could I rework my function so that it works as intended while not having to use a fixed height value?
I can't use handy jQuery methods like toggle(), show() or hide() because all of those hide an object entirely instead of accepting a minimum and maximum height or something like that. 
I'm open to different solutions with JS / JQuery / CSS, but the html structure should remain unchanged.

Comment: It is calculating the max-height within the 1.2 seconds.  In your example it reches the height after ~0.2 - 0.3 seconds, because the list is only 200px height. The rest of the time he is still calculating to 1200px. The best way to understand this, is to inspect the list element with firebug while clicking on the text.

Comment: Oouh sh*t you're right, thank you. Any idea how I could rework my function so that it works as intended without having to use a fixed height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for the first part:

```
if (!list.hasClass('opened')) {
    list.animate({
        maxHeight: '1200px'
    }, {
        duration: 1200,
        progress: function(){
            if(list.css('maxHeight') > list.css('height')) {
                $(this).stop();
            }
        },
        always: function() {
            $('#show_more').text('(weniger anzeigen)'); 
            list.addClass('opened');
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit:**
I reworked your code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/z83cpbvj/1/

> @progress ([jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)) A function to be called after each step of the animation, only once per animated element regardless of the number of animated properties.
>
> @always ([jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)) A function to be called when the animation completes or stops without completing

Comment: Cool! I found another way that gives me a little more control about the duration of the animation; Having the maxHeight get as high as the `.scrollHeight` of the list element. I'll try to incorporate the `always` argument to shorten the overall function as well (gives me a syntax error when I try it, I'll take a look at the reworked js fiddle ...). Thanks!

Comment: Cheers :-)  Don't hesitate to post your code, if you are stuck!